# Alternative to Capybara for Specflow

Tags: cucumber, capybara, specflow

I am planning of using Specflow for .NET. I come from a RoR background, and I have used Cucumber and Capybara. From what I have heard, Specflow is similar to Cucumber; however, does it have features that Capybara provides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it Capybara is using Selenium as the web driver.  You may want to check out an article on developers who are using Selenium with SpecFlow.

http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=112

Answer (score 7):

Coypu is the answer, I think: https://github.com/featurist/coypu

Comment: is it a headless browser? Have you given it a try? And have you given Watin and SimpleBrowser a try too?

Comment: no, it's an abstraction above WaTin/Specflow, so you can exchange it and aren't tightly coupled to the underlying driver. But if you're so focused on IE anyway (WaTin runs faster in IE, but that's almost all the benefits over Selenium I can think of) that's fine. 
Also, for headless browser, there are two main choices I know of: PhantomJs is headless and also understands Javascript/SVG, and is used by the Chutzpah VS2012 Extension to run JS tests in VS (very good option imo), and the other is Zombie.js if you are affine to JS and are familiar with Node.js/need max perf

Comment: oh sorry, I actually didn't use any of these, so no, a coworker did (which isn't a coworker anymore, no chance asking him)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using **Watin** engine to simulate browser. Watin runs mainly on IE.

In some occasions, I do not need the overhead of launching an entire browser to run my specflow tests. In those cases, I use **SimpleBrowser** (headless browser).